# Load a CSV file in Hive with lines of different length

Tags: database, database-design, hadoop, hive, hiveql

How can I do to load a CSV file in Hive with each line having a different number of columns ?
The problem is that each line have an undefined number of fields, otherwise I would have created a table with the maximum number of fields my CSV can have ...

Fields 1 to 5 will always be there. However, fields 6 to Infinity may not always be there.
A solution that might be acceptable would be to concatenate fields 6 to Infinity while importing the file in Hive.

Is that even possible ?

Here is a sample of my CSV file to make it clear :

```
data11;data12;data13;data14
data21;data22;data23;data24;data25
data31;data32;data33;data34;data35;data36
data41;data42;data43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options I can think of:

If the number of possible fields is not truly infinite but just higher than 5, then you can simply define all of those fields, and the ones not present in the data will just be null.

You could write a custom SerDe.

Or you could set the delimiter to something not present in the data, then use regex to extract the fields yourself. Example:

```
create table a(line string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\A';

create view b as
select
regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 1) as col1,
regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 2) as col2,
regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 3) as col3,
regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 4) as col4,
regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 5) as col5,
split(regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 6), '\;') as rest
from a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for your answers, it helped me very much.

I chose the third option that I modified a bit because it seemed that fields 6 to Infinity (which of course is not really Infinite) didn't insert properly in the last column. Indeed, only field 6 was inserted into the view "b".

I concatenated fields 6 to Infinity in the same string but separated with a pipe char "|".
Here is the modified code :

```
create view b as
select
regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 1) as col1,
regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 2) as col2,
regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 3) as col3,
regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 4) as col4,
regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)', 5) as col5,
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(line, '([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;([^\;]*)\;(.*)', 6), '\;', '|') as rest
from a;
```